# Java: Drawing with if-else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, colors, drawing

I am having trouble getting if-else statement to draw correct colors for my program. I'm under the impression that the if-statements are not organized correctly with the else statement and the "setColor," I am stumped on how to make the black render as yellow. The best way to describe it is to show it.

I'd appreciate ***any*** help!

My output (wrong):

[image: Wrong output]

Goal output (right):

[image]

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class IfGridEx3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400, 400);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();

        int sizeX = 40;
        int sizeY = 40;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {               
                int cornerX = x*sizeX;
                int cornerY = y*sizeY;

                if (x > 1)
                    if (x < 8)
                        if (y > 1)
                            if (y < 8)
                                g.setColor(Color.green);
                            else
                                g.setColor(Color.yellow);


                g.fillRect(cornerX+1, cornerY+1, sizeX-2, sizeY-2);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawString("x="+x, cornerX+10, cornerY+15);  // text is positioned at its baseline
                g.drawString("y="+y, cornerX+10, cornerY+33);  // offsets from the corner do centering      
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` is based only on result of last `if`, so `g.setColor(Color.yellow);` will be invoked only if all conditions

```
            if (x > 1)
                if (x < 8)
                    if (y > 1)
```

will be true (otherwise condition in last `if` will not even be tested),
and result evaluation of condition from last `if`

```
                        if (y < 8)
```

will be `false`. It means, that `else` will not be invoked if previous 3 conditions are `false`, which is why you are seeing some areas unset.

To solve this problem you can create *single* condition for center area

```
if (x > 1 && x < 8 && y > 1 && y < 8){
    g.setColor(Color.green);
} else {
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
}
```

Comment: `g.setColor(x > 1 && x < 8 && y > 1 && y < 8 ? Color.green : Color.yellow);`

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Yes, that is also nice idea, but I don't want to include it in answer to not overcomplicate things by introducing OP new concept. Anyway +1 for idea.

Comment: It worth mentioning, because the concept isn't hard and is "on topic" for conditionals. As it is the next step in learning conditionals, if the OP grasped the `if - else` you proposed, s/he'll have a good basis to understand this one too. (what I'm saying: it's good that you explained it using the basics, but is better if you also offer an opportunity to expand the leaning)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 if((x>=2 && x<=7) && (y>=2 &&y<=7))
//fill color green
else
//fill yello color
```